# iOS: Subclassing a subclassed UICollectionViewCell with same outlets/layout, but without second xib?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've created a UICollectionView subclass, OriginalCollectionViewCell.swift with a corresponding xib file.
Then I created a subclass of that, called SecondCollectionViewCell.swift, but I do not want to create a new xib file which feels excessive since they will look the same, and we shouldn't repeat ourselves. The only difference will be in code later.

```
class OriginalCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    
}

class SecondCollectionViewCell: OriginalCollectionViewCell {
    
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "OriginalCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            let cell: OriginalCollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! OriginalCollectionViewCell
            cell.label.text = "original cell \(indexPath.row+1)"
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell: SecondCollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SecondCollectionViewCell
            cell.label.text = "second cell \(indexPath.row+1)"
            return cell
        }
    }

}
```

However, when I try to cast to SecondCollectionViewCell, I get:

Could not cast value of type 'TestSubclasses.OriginalCollectionViewCell' (0x100cd9c10) to 'TestSubclasses.SecondCollectionViewCell' (0x100cd9b90).

Is there a way to cast without creating a second xib file?

Comment: You need to clarify the "differences" you're trying to deal with. From what you've shown, there is no reason to have a second cell class.

Comment: Eventually there are 3 subclasses to the original one. The differences will require different backend calls, and popover different presentationcontrollers. Each subclasses will also dynamically add different subviews programmatically. But it also has some complex UI that looks the same for each one (hence adding that 3 times will break D.R.Y. principles). Don't want everything in 1 file because it will get messy with switch-statements.

We're using a collectionView for such a thing because tvOS reasons. But the above logic also applies to iOS, which is more common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find it much (**much**) easier if you use "code" classes rather than a xib.

Define a "base" cell class with all your "common" elements.

Make each addition cell class subclasses of your base cell, each with its own "distinct" elements.

Here is a quick, very simple example:

- the "base" class adds a label at the top
- the "first" cell subclass adds a Green label below the base class's label, and sets background color to Dark Green
- the "second" cell subclass adds a Blue label below the base class's label, and sets background color to Cyan
- for variety, the "third" cell subclass adds **two** Red labels below the base class's label, and sets background color to Orange

The only thing this needs is a View Controller in your Storyboard set to `TestViewController` class, and a default Collection View added and connected to `@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!`:

```
class BaseCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let baseLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonBaseInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonBaseInit()
    }
    func commonBaseInit() -> Void {
        baseLabel.textAlignment = .center
        baseLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        baseLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(baseLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            baseLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            baseLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            baseLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -4.0),
        ])
        // so we can see it easily
        baseLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
}

class FirstCollectionViewCell: BaseCollectionViewCell {
    
    let firstLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonSubInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonSubInit()
    }
    func commonSubInit() -> Void {
        firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(firstLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            firstLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            firstLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            firstLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            firstLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),
        ])
        firstLabel.textAlignment = .center
        // so we can see it easily
        firstLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.6, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

}

class SecondCollectionViewCell: BaseCollectionViewCell {

    let secondLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonSubInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonSubInit()
    }
    func commonSubInit() -> Void {
        secondLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(secondLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            secondLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            secondLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            secondLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            secondLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),
        ])
        secondLabel.textAlignment = .center
        // so we can see it easily
        secondLabel.backgroundColor = .blue
        secondLabel.textColor = .white
        contentView.backgroundColor = .cyan
    }

}

class ThirdCollectionViewCell: BaseCollectionViewCell {

    let thirdLabel = UILabel()
    let anotherLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonSubInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonSubInit()
    }
    func commonSubInit() -> Void {
        thirdLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(thirdLabel)
        anotherLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(anotherLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            thirdLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            thirdLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            
            anotherLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            anotherLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -4.0),

            anotherLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            anotherLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdLabel.widthAnchor),
            
            thirdLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),
        ])
        thirdLabel.textAlignment = .left
        anotherLabel.textAlignment = .right
        // so we can see it easily
        thirdLabel.backgroundColor = .red
        thirdLabel.textColor = .yellow
        anotherLabel.backgroundColor = .red
        anotherLabel.textColor = .yellow
        contentView.backgroundColor = .orange
    }

}

class TestViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.register(FirstCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "firstCell")
        self.collectionView.register(SecondCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "secondCell")
        self.collectionView.register(ThirdCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "thirdCell")
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        var cell: UICollectionViewCell?

        switch indexPath.row % 3 {
        case 1:
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath)
            if let c = cell as? SecondCollectionViewCell {
                // set "Second Cell" specific properties
                c.secondLabel.text = "\(indexPath.item)"
            }

        case 2:
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "thirdCell", for: indexPath)
            if let c = cell as? ThirdCollectionViewCell {
                // set "Third Cell" specific properties
                c.thirdLabel.text = "\(indexPath.item)"
                c.anotherLabel.text = "A"
            }

        default:
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath)
            if let c = cell as? FirstCollectionViewCell {
                // set "First Cell" specific properties
                c.firstLabel.text = "\(indexPath.item)"
            }
            
        }

        if let c = cell as? BaseCollectionViewCell {
            // set base (common) properties, if they change
            c.baseLabel.text = "Common Label \(indexPath)"
        }

        guard let c = cell else {
            fatalError("We did something wrong!")
        }
        return c
    }
    
}
```

Example output (30 cells, rotating through first, second and third cell classes):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be registered separately with a different identifier like

```
collectionView.register(SecondCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
```

Downcasting is only possible. It's the other way around here.

Comment: Tried that, but since this doesn't connect to the nib, it doesn't have the label outlet property